# Django Invalid block tag: 'static' means what exactly?

Tags: python, django

(I'm using Django 1.3 - Python 2.7)

Been through all the related questions without any resolution.

The syntax error is in line 5, not line one:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}">
```

After reviewing related questions, some suggested first line should change to:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

I tried that, instead of "Invalid block tag: 'static'" error, I get :

> 'staticfiles' is not a valid tag library: Template library staticfiles not found, tried django.templatetags.staticfiles,django.contrib.admin.templatetags.staticfiles

I double checked the setting files:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/username/mysite/static'
# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
# Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
'django.contrib.admin',
# Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
# 'django.contrib.admindocs',
'mysite.myapp',
 )
```

Turned "Debug = False"

... and other suggestions. But I still get the same two errors.

The file structure is:

mysite contains the following folders/files: myapp
       , media
       , static
       , settings.py
       , ...

myapp contains the following folders/files: static
      , templates
      , views.py
      , ...

both mysite -> static and myapp -> static contain identical folders and files.

Please ask if you require more information.

Any help/direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You really **must not** use Django 1.3. It is many years old, totally unsupported, and definitely insecure. Upgrade to a more recent version.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm using the "Pythonanywhere" service and the pre installed version of Django is 1.3, I guess it is to support the old websites that have been served by them (the ones still using python 2.7). I will take your advise and jump to the latest version. Thanks.

Comment: All their Django environments are out of date, but their 2.7 environment is just ridiculous. You should really use a custom environment so you can install a supported version, and just as important, the latest bugfix/security release of the version you're using (the reason you use a supported version in the first place). All supported Django versions (1.8LTS, 1.9, 1.10) still support Python 2.7, so that's not an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Django 1.3 there's no static tag, and you must use it like this:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/hi.jpg" />
```

or add static to TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS and use STATIC_URL directly from template:

```
#  settings.py
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    #  other processors
    ’django.core.context_processors.static’,
)

#  some.html
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/hi.jpg" />
```

Comment: I used:  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/home.css"> : and it worked perfect, thanks a lot mate.